# Can I flash Linux on Apple TV A1469?

Tags: unix, appletv, jailbreak

I'm looking for a way to flash Linux (pihole to be more specific) on my old Apple TV Model A1469. Searched a lot but only found a way to do in the 1st gen. Any way I can do this?